# Как создать контроллер в slim 4?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, slim, slim4

В официальной документации slim 4 написано

> Container Resolution You are not limited to defining a function for
>   your routes. In Slim there are a few different ways to define your
>   route action functions.
>
> In addition to a function, you may use:
>
> container_key:method Class:method Class implementing __invoke() method
>   container_key This functionality is enabled by Slim’s Callable
>   Resolver Class. It translates a string entry into a function call.
>   Example:
>
> ```
> $app->get('/', '\HomeController:home');
> Alternatively, you can take advantage of PHP’s ::class operator which works well with IDE lookup systems and produces the same result:
>
> $app->get('/', \HomeController::class . ':home');
> In this code above we are defining a / route and telling Slim to execute the home() method on the HomeController class.
> ```
>
> Slim first looks for an entry of HomeController in the container, if
>   it’s found it will use that instance otherwise it will call it’s
>   constructor with the container as the first argument. Once an instance
>   of the class is created it will then call the specified method using
>   whatever Strategy you have defined.
>
> Registering a controller with the container Create a controller with
>   the home action method. The constructor should accept the dependencies
>   that are required. For example:
>
> ```
> <?php
>
> class HomeController
> {
>     protected $view;
>
>     public function __construct(\Slim\Views\Twig $view) {
>         $this->view = $view;
>     }
>
>     public function home($request, $response, $args) {
>       // your code here
>       // use $this->view to render the HTML
>       return $response;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Create a factory in the container that instantiates the controller
>   with the dependencies:
>
> ```
> $container = $app->getContainer();
> $container->set('HomeController', function (ContainerInterface $c) {
>     $view = $c->get('view'); // retrieve the 'view' from the container
>     return new HomeController($view);
> });
> ```
>
> This allows you to leverage the container for dependency injection and
>   so you can inject specific dependencies into the controller.

Но к сожалению, повторив всё это, я получаю ошибку

> "Callable \HomeController does not exist"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка возникает из-за того, что Ваш контроллер находится в контейнере под ключом `HomeController`, а приложение ищет обработчик по ключу `\HomeController`.

Попробуйте указать одинаковые значения в роутинге и инициализации контейнера.

```
$container->set(\HomeController::class, function (ContainerInterface $c) {
    $view = $c->get('view'); // retrieve the 'view' from the container
    return new HomeController($view);
});

// ...

$app->get('/', \HomeController::class . ':home');
```